# Chromatic number proof verification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-verification

*Prove that $χ(G) ≤ 1 + \text{max}\{\text{deg}_{G} (x): x ∈ V\}$ holds for every (finite)
graph $G = (V, E)$.*

Let's consider the worst case for graph colouring. To obtain the maximal case, we connect every vertex to every other vertex (the complete graph $K_n$). So, for every $v \in V(G)$ its degree is $n-1$, each has the maximal degree. For each of the $n-1$ neighbours we have to colour them with $n-1$ distinct colours. Additionally, the vertex $v$ must also be coloured using a distinct colour, using altogether $n$ colours.

This gives us the upper bound $χ(G) = 1 + \text{max}\{\text{deg}_{G} (x): x ∈ V\}$, every other possible graph must use fewer edges, so the chromatic number must also be smaller (or equal), because we cannot increase the chromatic number by removing edges.

Answer (score 3):

This proof is not compelling because $K_n$ need not be any kind of worst case.
Suppose you have a graph $G$ with $60$ vertices, all of degree $\le 3$. How do you conclude that $G$ is 4-colourable from the fact that $K_{60}$ is 61-colourable? (Or: How do you relate $G$ with its $60$ vertices to $K_4$?)

Please try again (or ask for a hint?)

Comment: I understand your point... I will try to think of something new.

Comment: would induction be advisable in this case?

Comment: @LearnToMath Definitely. For example, let $G'$ be obtained from $G$ by removing a vertex. How can you obtain a colouring of $G$ from a colouring of $G'$?

Comment: Base: we have 1 vertex; $1 \leq 1+1$. Step: let's assume the statement holds for every graph $G'$ of $k$ vertices, show that this implies that the statement holds for any graph G of $k+1$ vertices. If I have $G$ and I remove a vertex, i'm not sure how I can follow. I can only come up with a similar argument than my initial wrong one. That if the removed vertex is of maximum degree, we can color G' with one less color.

Comment: Say you remove a vertex $v$ of max degree $\Delta$.  Then $G - v$ has max degree at most $\Delta$, and thus is $\Delta + 1$ colorable.  Keep the same colloring, and add back $v$.  This guy has $\Delta$ neighbors.  At worst, each neighbor has a different color.  The rest is up to you.