# Doubt about chromatic number proof

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm in a discrete math course and was trying to prove the following theorem:

> A graph G with $\Delta(G) = k$ ($\Delta(G)$ is the max vertex degree) is $(k+1)-$coloreable.

I've tried my own, and I've read the answers in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024835/chromatic-number-proof-verification), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952410/question-about-the-proof-that-a-graph-with-maximum-degree-at-most-k-is-k-1?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545377/fewest-colors-d1-needed-to-color-graph-with-some-maximal-degree-d-inducting-on?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I still have a big doubt using an induction proof as shown in [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952410/question-about-the-proof-that-a-graph-with-maximum-degree-at-most-k-is-k-1?rq=1).

In the induction step, when we delete a vertex *v* of the graph $G$ with $\Delta(G) = k$: What garantees me that once the vertex is deleted, $\Delta(G)$ is stil ***k***? As they show that $\Delta(G') = k$, what garantees that?

PD: pardon my english, I'm not native speaker.

Comment: Are you dead set on using induction? The easiest proof of this that I could think of would be to use the greedy coloring algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time yes I though using it, but I'm requested on using induction. I've tought on using two scenarios: one in which the vertex  I delete is not adjacent to the vertex with highest degree, and the other in which are two vertex of max degree adjacent and I delete one of them. Still, I'm wondering if there's a straight formulation, or why is the proposed in the previous questions valid and not dealing with this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s entirely possible that after $v$ is removed, the maximum degree of the resulting graph $H$ is less than $k$. It doesn’t matter: the result being proved at that link is that if $\Delta(G)\color{red}{\le}k$, then $G$ is $k$-colorable. We assumed that $\Delta(G)\le k$, and removing a vertex cannot increase the maximum degree, so $\Delta(H)\le k$, and we can apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thank U for that!!! I was thinking that, $H$ should be $\Delta(H) \leq k $ instead $\Delta(H) = k $ and that would make more sense to me. I can see the demonstration sense, but the = was bothering me.

Comment: @dante95: You’re welcome!